# Task.Run() not working as expected - "cannot implicitly convert type void to object"

Tags: c#, task

I have a method I need to call on a separate thread in a "fire and forget" fashion, that is, I just start it and move on, without waiting for a result. I'm using Task.Run() to achieve this. From what examples I've seen, this should work. However when I run this I get a

> "cannot implicitly convert type void to object" exception.

The part that gets highlighted in VS is **PollForPaymentStatus(request, regulator)**, i.e. the method call. The method itself doesn't seem to get called. What am I doing wrong?

```
        public void StartPollingForPaymentStatus(dynamic request, Regulator regulator)
        {
            Task.Run(() => PollForPaymentStatus(request, regulator));
        }

        // Run this in a separate thread!
        private void PollForPaymentStatus(dynamic request, Regulator regulator)
        {
            int attemptNumber = 0;
            while (attemptNumber < _maximumPollingAttempts)
            {
               attemptNumber++;

                var response = SendGet(_paymentUrl + "/" + request.Id, regulator);
                if(response.status == 'Success'){
                 // do stuff and return 
                }
                Thread.Sleep(pollingInterval);
            }
        }
```

Edit:

I managed to make it work by putting the call to PollForPaymentStatus inside an anonymous method body, rather than calling it directly.

```
           public void StartPollingForPaymentStatus(dynamic request, Regulator regulator)
            {
                Task.Run(() => 
               {
              PollForPaymentStatus(request, regulator)
               };
            );
        }
```

Does anyone know what the key difference between these two approaches is? Why does one work and not the other?

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Your latter code is clear that nothing is returned (since there is no `return`). Your former code is not the same as the latter code.

*Since at compile time it isn't clear whether something is returned (due to use of `dynamic`).*

The former code is equivalent to

```
public void StartPollingForPaymentStatus(dynamic request, Regulator regulator)
{
    Task.Run(() => 
    {
      return PollForPaymentStatus(request, regulator)
    });
}
```

You can validate this by putting `var g =`  before the `Task.Run` and then hovering over `g`. The former code has `g` as `Task<dynamic>`. The latter code has `g` as `Task` (which is what you want).

Alas, at runtime something *isn't* returned - so **BOOM**.